# GNSS module direct grounding to ESP32 increase sensitivity

Tags: grounding, gps, ground-plane, esp32, snr

I have a simple cirquit that composes of the following :

- ESP32-DevKit-LiPo (ESP32-WROOM)
- GNSS Module Beitian BN-357P with ufl connector for external antenna
- GNSS Active Patch Antenna

My simple is schematic is as follows

[image]

I program the esp32 to bridge the bluetooth to the GPS Uart so I can read the NMEA messages from my mobile with the help of GPS Bluetooth Aplications.

During Installation ia small box I installed a small pla thin sheet between the module and the esp32 so not to have a short cirquit.

These are the stats I had:

[image]

Then I removed the insulation sheet and put the gps module upside down so **its ground shield would touch the esp32 ground shield**.

[image]

Then the satellite stats had great increase:

[image]

When the module didnt touch then the sattelite signal decreased significantly.
The pin to pin ground connection between gnss and esp32 is fine and the cable is about 5cm.
**How is this explained?**
Is somehow the ground connection more direct and "cleaner" ?
Maybe the bluetooth antenna proximity?

Comment: Where is the GPS antenna of the module installed and can you search for the antenna diagram?

Comment: The gps module has no antenna. I connect an external active patch antenna through the ufl connector

Comment: @vicatcu yes both explanation seems viable. I will try to add thicker cable to the wiring to see if anything changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the ground wire connecting the two modules being "thicker" might have similar results. Based on what you are telling us, the only difference between the two circumstances is that the more favorable one has "less resistance between the two grounds." More resistance between the two grounds will generally result in the voltage on the two modules being more different than you might guess, and notably the voltage the GPS module is getting might be effectively reduced relative to its local GND, making it perform less well.

Another possibility is that current flowing through the ground wire connecting the two modules is generating radiated emission that interferes with the GPS receiver's sensitivity (signal-to-noise ratio), so the circumstance with the shorter connection where this current flows minimizes that effect.

Comment: I am also designing a pcb to accomodate these two modules. I suspect that I should minimize the distance of the trace between the ground pin of the module and the ground pin of esp32?

Comment: Yea, if you do that I would highly recommend using (at least) a 4-layer design with an internal plane dedicated to GND and an internal plane dedicated to power.